# Show Fxcop errors as compilation errors in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, fxcop

Is there any way so that I get the Fxcop errors displayed as compilation errors in Visual Studio build?

**P.S** - I dont want to integrate Fxcop into an MSBuild script. I just need it to be integrated into VS 2008, and when "Build Solution" is run, it should display the Fxcop errors if any.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the project, choose Properties.

On the Code Analysis tab, choose "Enable Code Analysis on Build".

[image]

Comment: as the screenshot shows, you have used VS 2010. can this be done in Vs 2008? I cant see any "Code Analysis" tab in VS 2008.

Comment: just googled some more on this.. they say Code Analysis is not provided as a feature in VS 2008 Professional Edition, the one which I'm using :( 

Is there any workaround for this to be achieved in VS 2008 Professional Edition ???

Answer (score 1):

For an edition of Visual Studio that does not include integrated Code Analysis, you have a couple of options.  The simplest is to run FxCop as a post-build event, redirecting output to the console:

`"$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft FxCop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /file:"$(TargetPath)" /console`

This will add the FxCop warnings and errors to your Visual Studio error list, and allow you to navigate to source code when context information is available for a violation. but that's pretty much it.

If you want support for functionality like adding SuppressMessage attributes from the error list, you'll need a Visual Studio extension of some sort.  (That's how the integrated Code Analysis piece works.)